# How to fix "`FromSql<Timestamptz, _>` is not implemented for `bool`" error?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

This problem only started when I added the datetime fields. If I remove them then it works:

```ini
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["postgres", "chrono"] }
chrono = "0.4"
```

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate diesel;

use chrono::{DateTime, Utc};
use diesel::Queryable;

table! {
    store (id) {
        id -> Int4,
        name -> Varchar,
        description -> Varchar,
        created_at -> Timestamptz,
        updated_at -> Timestamptz,
        is_active -> Bool,
        created_by -> Int4,
        address_id -> Int4,
    }
}

#[derive(Queryable)]
struct Store {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    is_active: bool,
    created_by: i32,
    address_id: i32,
    created_at: DateTime<Utc>,
    updated_at: DateTime<Utc>,
}

#[test]
fn it_works() {
    use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
    use diesel::prelude::*;

    let database_url = std::env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    let conn = PgConnection::establish(&database_url)
        .expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url));

    use crate::store::dsl::*;

    let user = store
        .filter(id.eq(1))
        .limit(1)
        .load::<Store>(&conn)
        .expect("Error loading posts");
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `bool: FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, _>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:46:24
     |
46   |         .load::<Store>(&conn)
     |          ----          ^^^^^ the trait `FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, _>` is not implemented for `bool`
     |          |
     |          required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the trait `FromSql<diesel::sql_types::Bool, Pg>` is implemented for `bool`
     = note: required for `bool` to implement `Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, _>`
     = note: 2 redundant requirements hidden
     = note: required for `Store` to implement `Queryable<(Integer, Text, Text, diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, diesel::sql_types::Timestamptz, diesel::sql_types::Bool, Integer, Integer), _>`
     = note: required for `SelectStatement<table, DefaultSelectClause, NoDistinctClause, WhereClause<Eq<id, Bound<Integer, i32>>>, NoOrderClause, LimitClause<Bound<BigInt, i64>>>` to implement `LoadQuery<_, Store>`

... more of the same errors snipped ...
```

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is due to field order. The order of fields in your SQL does not match your structs.

From [Diesel Getting Started](http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/):

> Using `#[derive(Queryable)]` assumes that the order of fields on the `Post` struct matches the columns in the `posts` table, so make sure to define them in the order seen in the `schema.rs` file.

The error message said it couldn't convert a `Bool` to a timestamp, so it mixed up your `is_active` with one of the date fields. Re-order your struct to match (or vice versa):

```
#[derive(Queryable)]
struct Store {
    id: i32,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    created_at: DateTime<Utc>,
    updated_at: DateTime<Utc>,
    is_active: bool,
    created_by: i32,
    address_id: i32,
}
```

See also: [Why does order of fields in struct need to match table! in Diesel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77169378)