# Why does order of fields in struct need to match table! in Diesel?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

Sometimes when defining tables and writing queries, you may encounter an error like:

- "the trait bound `(_, _, _): CompatibleType<_, DB>` is not satisfied" or
- "the trait bound `_: FromSql<_, DB>` is not satisfied"

which doesn't appear to be from a field type mismatch, but then you find out later that it was simply because the fields for the struct and the columns in the `table!` definition are in different order.

Here's an example:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;

table! {
    users {
        id -> Int4,
        name -> Text,
        favorite_number -> Int4,
    }
}

#[derive(Queryable)]
struct User {
    id: i32,
    favorite_number: i32,
    name: String,
}

fn get_users() -> Vec<User> {
    users::table.load::<User>(&mut get_connection()).unwrap()
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, Integer): load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<User, Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:19:31
     |
19   |     users::table.load::<User>(&mut get_connection()).unwrap()
     |                  ----         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<User, Pg>` is not implemented for `(Integer, diesel::sql_types::Text, Integer)`
     |                  |
     |                  required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
     = help: the following other types implement trait `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<U, DB>`:
               (ST0,)
               (ST0, ST1)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6)
               (ST0, ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7)
             and 24 others
     = note: required for `users::table` to implement `LoadQuery<'_, _, User>`
note: required by a bound in `diesel::RunQueryDsl::load`
    --> /home/kmdreko/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/diesel-2.1.1/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1543:15
     |
1541 |     fn load<'query, U>(self, conn: &mut Conn) -> QueryResult<Vec<U>>
     |        ---- required by a bound in this associated function
1542 |     where
1543 |         Self: LoadQuery<'query, Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `RunQueryDsl::load`
```

Its even worse when your unordered fields have the same type so you don't get a compile-time error but you get mismatched data.

Why does the field order matter more than field name? Couldn't Diesel use the name instead of the order? Is there a way to query where order doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Diesel prefers deserializing by index instead of by name.

---

To be absolutely clear, yes order matters. In the Diesel documentation [it says](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/prelude/derive.Queryable.html):

> When this trait is derived, it will assume that **all fields on your struct** matches **all fields in the query**, including the order and count. This means that field order is significant if you’re using `#[derive(Queryable)]`. **Field name has no effect.**

User-defined structs with Diesel traits and `table!`s are fairly independent things. They are often used in concert with each other, but they don't have to and must be able to work independently.

> Why does the field order matter more than field name?

One reason comes down to flexibility:

1. A struct implementing [`Queryable`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html) can be used to load data without being directly tied to a particular table (e.g. an join set, a sub-view, transformed columns). Here you can see it used to reflect the result of an aggregate query:

   ```
   #[derive(Queryable)]
   struct UserSummary {
       user_name: String,
       total_posts: i64,
   }

   fn get_user_summaries() -> Vec<UserSummary> {
       users::table
           .inner_join(posts::table)
           .group_by(users::id)
           .select((users::name, diesel::dsl::count(posts::id)))
           .load::<UserSummary>(&mut get_connection())
           .unwrap()
   }
   ```

   You'll also notice that the type has `user_name` and `total_posts` fields, but the query works without those identifiers being used in the query itself. That is because the mapping from columns to fields works by their order and not by name. So in this example, the `UserSummary` only needs to match the type and order of fields used from the `.select()` clause.

   Behind the scenes, the Diesel syntax above ultimately builds an SQL query that will return `(Text, Bigint)` and the `Queryable` trait on our struct basically just builds a mapping from those SQL types to our Rust type. This allows user-defined types the freedom to be used in more places and not tied to a specific table or set of tables.
2. A `table!` definition can reasonably be used with no user-defined struct at all.

   ```
   table! {
       users (id) {
           id -> Int4,
           name -> Text,
       }
   }

   fn get_user_names() -> Vec<(i32, String)> {
       users::table
           .load::<(i32, String)>(&mut get_connection())
           .unwrap()
   }
   ```

   There is no need to define a struct for our table if we don't want to. It maps into the query syntax in the same way as above: the `users::table` essentially yields rows of `(Integer, Text)` and we can map from that as a tuple instead of a struct.

So order matters when using them independently to help them stay versatile. As such order definitely matters when using them together.

---

> Couldn't Diesel use the name instead of the order?

It has the capability; the [`Row`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/row/trait.Row.html) trait allows you to `.get()` by `&str` instead of by `usize`. This is why you always `.select()` by `<table name>::<field name>` so the Diesel syntax can track the name as well as the type.

But another big reason for not doing so is for performance. It is much more efficient to load a field from a row if its index is statically known. The alternative would be to perform a lookup to get the index by the column name, but that would have to be done for each field of each row.

---

> Is there a way to query where order doesn't matter?

Yes, depending on your use-case and tenacity:

1. You can rely on field names yourself in a custom [`FromSqlRow`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/deserialize/trait.FromSqlRow.html) implementation.
2. There is also the [`QueryableByName`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/prelude/trait.QueryableByName.html) trait. But this trait is only used when deserializing from a raw [`sql_query`](https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/dsl/fn.sql_query.html) where the docs note that *"unlike most queries in Diesel, `sql_query` will deserialize its data by name, not by index"*. It cannot be used with other Diesel syntax.
3. You can derive `Selectable` as use `User::as_select()` before loading the data:

   ```
   use diesel::prelude::*;

   table! {
       users {
           id -> Int4,
           name -> Text,
           favorite_number -> Int4,
       }
   }

   #[derive(Queryable, Selectable)]
   #[diesel(table_name = users)]
   #[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg)]
   struct User {
       id: i32,
       favorite_number: i32,
       name: String,
   }

   fn get_users() -> Vec<User> {
       users::table
           .select(User::as_select())
           .load::<User>(&mut get_connection())
           .unwrap()
   }
   ```

   This is an alternative to `users::all_columns` when using `.select()`. It will automatically construct a select clause that matches your result struct in field order.

   The `check_for_backend(_)` attribute is helpful since it also instructs the `#[derive(Selectable)]` macro to generate additional compile-time checks to improve error messages generated by field type mismatches. However, this only compares fields with the same names and doesn't consider order.

Overall though, it is simpler to just keep both in identical order.